# Trouble finding Vsat of an op-amp

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, current, amplifier

So I am using an LM741/A Op-Amp. Wondering whats the value of its Vsat? Have been looking at its datasheets but cannot find anything. Am I missing something? Is the Vsat just equal to its output voltage swing?

Answer (score 2):

[This data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf) says

> LM 741, +-15V supply, Output voltage swing : ±12(MIN) ±14 (TYP) for 10k ohm load

and

> LM 741 (A), +-20V supply, Output voltage swing : ±16(MIN) for 10k ohm load

Ti website also says "Rail-to-rail : No"

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/304522/238590

Comment: Ok so for a 2Kohm load, the Typical output voltage swing is 13V, and the minimum is 10V with a 15V power supply.LM371's maximum supply voltage is 22V.
Let's say I have another op-amp that has a typical output voltage swing for a 2Kohm as well of 12V and a minimum output swing of 10V with a 15V power
supply. This other op-amp has a max supply votage of 18V. Which op-amp do I use if I want an undistorted Vout peak voltage of 12.5V? Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: From what you said, +-15V supply would not work with either opamp. When you say *undistorted* you might also want to specify a frequency range and choose one with larger slew rate.

Comment: Yes the Vin frequency is 50Khz and both op-amps have suitable slew rates. Just wondering which op-amp I should choose taking into account the voltage swing. Both op-amps output swing can reach over 12.5V if supply votage is 18V. So which one do I use

Comment: "*... both op-amps have suitable slew rates.*" Can you show your calculations? Mine show that 50 kHz, 12.5 V peak means you require a slew rate of at least 12.5 V in one quarter cycle at 50 kHz so \$ slew\ rate = 12.5 \times \frac 1 4 \times \frac 1 {50k} = 62.5 \ \text{V/}\mu \text s \$. The datasheet you linked to says the 741 can do 0.5 V/μs and that's only at unity gain. I think you'll struggle.

Comment: Wouldn't the max rate expression for \$12.5 \sin(2\pi 50k\ t) \leftrightarrow 12.5 \cdot 2\pi\cdot 50k \cdot \max(cos(\cdot))\$ ? I got \$4 V/\mu s\$.

Comment: @AJN: Yes, I think you're correct. Pasting "d (12.5sin(2π50k t) )/dt" into https://www.wolframalpha.com/ gives 
3926.99 k cos(100 π k t) + 0 so when cosine = 1 that equates to 4 MV/s = 4 V/μs. I assumed, for simplicity,\ a triangle wave going from the zero-cross to V-peak in one quarter cycle. I can't see where I've gone wrong though.

Comment: This is old, but just for the record, a sine wave has a maximum dv/dt of about 1.5 times higher than the same peak voltage and frequency triangle wave. (actually π/2)

Answer (score 0):

The voltage saturation level is usually 1 or 2V less than power supply levels.
If your Voltage supply is + or - 15V, then \$V_{sat}\$ is likely to be + or - 12 or 13V. The maximum voltage swing is  about +13V or -13V.

Reference:

Page 133, Sedra and Smith -Microelectronic circuits 7e , Oxford university press.
*"An Op that is operating form power supplies of +/- 15V will saturate when the output which reaches +/- 13V"*.